# How to structure Firestore database for followers/following

Tags: database, data-structures, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I have an app where users can follow each other and I currently have a database structure which allows users to follow, unfollow and see their followers/following users, and see the number of followers/following they have.

The way I have structured my database is by having a users document stored in a usernames collections which contains their followers/following count, and all their info. Like profile image and display name etc.

Then, this users followers/following users are stored in a subcollection as a document. In this document, there is a document reference which points back to the root usernames collection, and to the following/followers users document, where i then pull their info if needed.

I was just wandering if there is a more efficient way to structure my database. This seems like the best option but I have a feeling their is an even better way which i am not thinking of.

Thank you

Comment: Personally I have found sub-collections for such uses not great as it is difficult to get to data from the other direction. Sure you can see all who that person follows, but what if you want all who follow that person? What we ended up doing is creating a collection to hold the following relationships. Think of a cross table in sql. This allows queries of all users who follow a person, or as easily all people who follow that person.

Comment: So i have two subcollections within each users document. One is Followers, and one is Following. It works quite well especially with using the document reference as i am able to go directly in to a followers or a person i am followings document and grab there information. Your fix however does seem efficient and i will definitely have a look at going about it that way. Thank you for your response I appreciate it

Comment: @Brettski Did you put user name in follow collection? If not, when you see following list, do you get every user document ?

Comment: @Watanabe.N We put the id field in the follow collection. When looking up all who follow someone, we return all those records and look up the id's in the user table to get the details needed. It's feels strange without joins, but has worked pretty well for us. Since our application has users also following partners, communities and sessions, all of these "follows" are stored using this same collection. I'd be happy to show you if you're interested.

Comment: Great. So do you run a "get followee document" as many times as the number of follows? I was curious about performance but I'm glad to hear it works in your case. Yes, it would be nice if you could share!

Comment: Yes, get as many documents as there are follows. It's unfortunately the way of Firestore it seems. I guess you could build triggers to update an integer field with the count, but in our case we want to know who those followers are. Haven't seen this thousands of followers. We figure we'll go Graph database as we get to more that scale. Sample to get count: https://github.com/ThatConference/that-api/blob/8effe9725faff92c68c9bcc1da7ba5e030acbdd1/src/dataSources/cloudFirestore/favorite.js#L93. Doesn't pull back the doc data, just docRefs. Hit me up on THAT.us and we can go over this live